# BindableCollection not found inside my xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was following a rather basic tutorial on how to implement lists in xaml that used Caliburn.micro's BindableCollection (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPhJz7CHnuQ). However, I simply can't get  to find my BindableCollection, and I've no idea why.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace CaliburnTest
{
    public class ClassWithBindable
    {
        public BindableCollection<TestElement> MyBindableCollection { get; set; }

        public ClassWithBindable()
        {
            List<TestElement> testElements = new List<TestElement>()
            {
                new TestElement(),
                new TestElement()
            };

            MyBindableCollection = new BindableCollection<TestElement>(testElements);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace CaliburnTest
{
    public class TestElement
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public TestElement()
        {
            Name = "Test";
            Description = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="CaliburnTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CaliburnTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyBindableCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The error I get is "No DataContext found for Binding 'MyBindableCollection' ". I tried creating a BindableCollection in other namespaces, notably under the MainWindow.cs folder, but it didn't make a difference, besides restarting VS and rebuilding the project multiple. I assume the answer is fairly simple but I'm running out of ideas, so any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to set the DataContext property of the MainWindow to an instance of your ClassWithBindable class, either in XAML or in code behind.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not sure how to set the DataContext properly. I tried writing "this.DataContext = new ClassWithBindable();" in the MainWindow.cs file, which didn't help, and tried moving the BindableCollection to MainWindow.cs and set the DataContext to this, which, again, didn't change anything.

Comment: That assignment should be sufficient to make the application work. You can ignore the complaints of the XAML Designer. Otherwise you also set a design-time DataContext.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed worked despite the error messsage!

Comment: Just in case, you may as well use the built-in ObservableCollection class.